# Silverlight 1px dotted line with no antialiasing

Tags: silverlight, antialiasing, stroke-dasharray

what I'm trying to achieve is having a dotted line being drawn from one edge of its parent to the other. Something similar to this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Line Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" X2="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualWidth}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid>
```

The thing is, the above only seems to work at design-time.

Problem #2 is that even if I succeed to draw something similar to this, it gets ruined by antialiasing.
I know SL does not have the SnapsToDevicePixels option, but neither UseLayoutRounding, nor the [PixelSnapper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx) could prevent my 1px dotted line from being spread across 2 pixel lines in certain scenarios.

Comment: Could you share a screen shot of what you're experiencing? Having trouble visualizing your issue and can't seem to reproduce.